как соединить классы из разных проектов в Intellij Idea?
я создал 2 проекта, которые должны соединять классы с друг-другом, но они не соединяют классы, а только видят файлы, но не видят классы, а собрать проекты я не могу потому что классы из разных проектов не соединяются и будет ошибка, пытался подключить классы путём File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Add -> JARs Dipectories, выбрал папку 2-го проекта и соединил, но классы не соединились.
